# updating a label value on the GUI which gets updated value from temperature sensor all the time

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-multithreading, signals-slots, slot

my project is to design a GUI window to get Temperature from temp sensor and display it on a label widget on the GUI. i was able to display the value but it's not updating on the label
please help. i was looking about how to emit signal in pyqt5 and connect it to the label widget

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from w1thermsensor import W1ThermSensor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot

sensor = (W1ThermSensor())

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, parent=None):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 40, 141, 71))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label.setNum(int(sensor.get_temperature()))
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.start()
        self.signals(self)
    def signals(self):
        self.threadclass.connect(self.updateLabel)
        self.threadclass.connect(pyqtSignal(val))
        self.pyqtSignal(val).connect(self.updateLabel)
    def updateLabel(self,val):
        val = int(sensor.get_temperature())
        self.label.setNum(val)
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    change_value = pyqtSignal(int)
    def setupUi(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)
    def run(self):
        while 1:
            val = int(sensor.get_temperature())
            self.change_value.emit(val)
            print (val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    ui.signals()
    Form.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various problems with your code:

- you are calling `self.signals(self)`, but `signals` does not accept arguments;
- connections are between signals and slots, but you're trying to connect to the `threadclass` instance, which is neither a signal nor a slot, but a QThread object;
- `self.threadclass.connect(pyqtSignal(val))` does not make much sense: `pyqtSignal` is a function used when a class is constructed, and can only be used as such; also, `val` is never declared in the scope of `signals()`;
- `self.pyqtSignal(val).connect(self.updateLabel)` doesn't work either: `self` is the Ui_Form instance, and has no `pyqtSignal` attribute; again, no `val` is declared;
- the python files generated with pyuic should **never** be edited, but used as imported modules only and all program implementation should happen in another class, not in the "ui" objects it creates (read more about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html));

Recreate the GUI if you don't have it anymore, and generate again the ui with pyuic. Then try to do something like this (supposing you've created a file named `ui_form.py`) *in a separate file*:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from ui_form import Ui_Form

class MyTest(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyTest, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.threadclass = ThreadClass()
        self.threadclass.change_value.connect(self.updateLabel)
        self.threadclass.start()

    def updateLabel(self, value):
        self.label.setNum(value)

class ThreadClass(QtCore.QThread):
    change_value = pyqtSignal(int)
    def setupUi(self, parent=None):
        super(ThreadClass, self).__init__(parent)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            val = int(sensor.get_temperature())
            # I suppose
            self.change_value.emit(val)
            print (val)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = MyTest
    test.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```